# Premium search API, use of retweets_of and from function

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I am using TwitterAPI in python3 for premium search to find archived tweets that are retweeted by user1 from user2 with specific keywords. After some suggestions, I have used https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/operators-by-product and https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI to make this code, but when I run the code I am not getting any output or error message.

The code works fine when I am not using the retweets_of and from operators, but these are the rules I want to use to get my data.

I know my code shows a premium Sandbox search, but I will upgrade it to premium Full Archive search when I have the right code.

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

#Keys and Tokens from Twitter Developer
consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

PRODUCT = '30day'
LABEL = 'MyLABELname'

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL),
            {'query':'retweets_of:user.Tesla from:user.elonmusk Supercharger battery'})

for item in r:
    print (item['text'] if 'text' in item else item)
```

Does someone know what the problem is with my code or is there any other way to use the retweets_of and from operators for a premium search. Is it also possible to add a count operator to my code so it will give numbers as output and not all of the tweets in writing?

Comment: Probably the value of your `query` parameter does not match tweets. Can you post the query with actual user names and keywords?

Comment: I edited the code above, and checked that it should be tweets matching the parameters, but still no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should omit "user." in your `query`.

Also, by specifying "Supercharger battery", which is perfectly fine, you require both in the search results. However, if you require only either word to be present, you would use "Supercharger OR battery".

Finally, to specify a larger number of results, use the `maxResults` parameter (10 to 100).

Here is your example with all of the above:

```
r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL),
        {'query':'retweets_of:Tesla from:elonmusk Supercharger OR battery',
         'maxResults':100})
```

Twitter's Premium Search doc may be helpful: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search.html